# Create Rough/Random Surface not working on correct side?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, proportional-editing

When I try to create a random surface using proportional editing it edits the opposite verticies that I selected.

Why are the bottom verticies being moved and not the top ones that are clearly selected?

Note I used g and proportional random to create this image below.

[image]

Comment: Proportional editing takes effect on things that are NOT selected.  Pick one vert on top and use a large proportional edit field.  If you need to, hide the bottom verts to stop them from being affected.

Comment: ah okay I will try that

Comment: also you could select all and S + Z + -1  ;)